# Google Places API: Do NearbySearch requests only return places with a business_status of OPERATIONAL?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm looking to map COVID-related business closures, but it seems that the NearbySearch feature only returns places that have a "business_status" constant of "OPERATIONAL."

Is this correct? If not are there optional parameters I'm missing that might return all nearby businesses regardless of business_status?

Answer (score 1):

Set "open_now" param to false, this will return all places and you can parse for non operational